# i have two tables student and trainer. i want to get values from student and trainer table based on some condition

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

i have **student** and **trainer** tables :

*student table:*

```
student_id (primary key)    
name    
email
```

*trainer table:*

```
trainer_id    
student_id    
amount
```

output has to:

```
sid name email amount  
22   ram   r@g   200  
34   sam   r@f
```

i want to get (student_id,name,email) from student table and (amount) from trainer table(imp : trainer_id and student_id should match(like sid = 46,tid =78,amount=500) then only the amount has to display value. otherwise amount will display empty but (student_id,name,email) should display)

in trainer table, student_id and trainer_id has to match...based on that amount will come..i mean if we send the select query as "select amount from trainer where student_id= 20 and trainer_id=36...". that column should match for sid and tid

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.  The best advice is to give example data for both tables and then show the output you expect.

Comment: What are your conditions?

Comment: in **trainer** table, student_id and trainer_id has to match...based on that **amount** will come..i mean if we send the select query as "select amount from trainer where student_id= 20 and trainer_id=36...". that column should match for sid and tid

Answer (score 0):

If you do it this way, It **wil not** show data if amount is empty :

```
select st.student_id, 
    st.name, 
    st.email, 
    tt.amount 
from student_table st, trainer_table tt 
where st.student_id = tt.student_id
```

NVL function lets you substitute a value when a null value is encountered,
so if you do it this way, It **wil** show data and show 0 instead of null:

```
select st.student_id,
   st.name,
   st.email,
   (nvl(select tt.amount
        from   trainer_table tt
        where  st.student_id = tt.student_id,0))) amount 
from student_table st
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with PLSQL. Sorry it is so extensive but I hope it allows you to see the power of PLSQL if you need to manipulate data based on conditionals.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE result_record IS RECORD
    ( sid NUMBER
    , name VARCHAR2(60)
    , email VARCHAR2(60)
    , amount NUMBER);
  CURSOR c IS select st.student_id sid, 
st.name name, 
st.email email, 
tt.amount amount
from student_table st, trainer_table tt 
where st.student_id = tt.student_id;

  TYPE results_table IS TABLE OF results_record INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  c_rec c%ROWTYPE;

  temp_rec RESULTS_RECORD;
  results RESULTS_TABLE;
  lv_index NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
  OPEN c;
  WHILE lv_index <= c%ROWCOUNT LOOP
    FETCH c INTO c_rec;
    temp_rec.sid := c_rec.sid;
    temp_rec.name := c_rec.name;
    temp_rec.email := c_rec.email;
    temp_rec.amount := c_rec.amount;
    results(lv_index) := temp_rec;
    lv_index := lv_index + 1;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c;
  -- Now we can access and modify our table from inside PLSQL
  SELECT * FROM results;
  -- Use PLSQL logic to make the table output pretty with '$' and conditionals
  FOR i IN results LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(i.sid||' $'||i.amount); -- example for how to access
     -- your code here
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

As always, I hope this gives you some ideas.

-V